# bash passing parameters to xml ed

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

Inside a bash script I want to pass arguments to the xml ed command of the xmlstarlet tools.
Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# this variable holds the arguments I want to pass
ED=' -u "/a/@id" -v NEW_ID -u "/a/b" -v NEW_VALUE'
# this variable holds the input xml
IN='
<a id="OLD_ID">
    <b>OLD_VALUE</b>
</a>
'
# here I pass the arguments manually
echo $IN | xml ed -u "/a/@id" -v NEW_ID -u "/a/b" -v NEW_VALUE input.xml
# here I pass them using the variable from above
echo $IN | xml ed $ED
```

Why does the first call work, ie it gives the desired result:

```
# echo $IN | xml ed -u "/a/@id" -v NEW_ID -u "/a/b" -v NEW_VALUE input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a id="NEW_ID">
  <b>NEW_VALUE</b>
</a>
```

While the second call does not work, ie it gives:

```
# echo $IN | xml ed $ED
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a id="OLD_ID">
  <b>OLD_VALUE</b>
</a>
```

Comment: Quotes are not processed when expanding a variable, so they'll be passed literally to the `xml` command.

Comment: so how would I work around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the double quotes, because they're not processed after expanding variables:

```
ED=' -u /a/@id -v NEW_ID -u /a/b -v NEW_VALUE'
```

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, it is better to use arrays for lists of options like this. In this case, it doesn't make a difference, since none of the items embedded in `ED` contain whitespace.

```
#!/bin/bash
# this variable holds the arguments I want to pass
ED=( -u "/a/@id" -v NEW_ID -u "/a/b" -v NEW_VALUE)
# this variable holds the input xml
IN='
<a id="OLD_ID">
    <b>OLD_VALUE</b>
</a>
'
# here I pass the arguments manually
echo $IN | xml ed -u "/a/@id" -v NEW_ID -u "/a/b" -v NEW_VALUE input.xml
# here I pass them using the variable from above
echo $IN | xml ed "${ED[@]}"
```

Comment: thanks for this pro-tip! makes life much easier and strings less convoluted :)